# How to find the style property of Dom element using Dom Document in PHP?

Tags: php, html, dom, domdocument

I use PHP Dom Document to read HTML Dom elements from file.

```
  $html = file_get_contents(public_path() . 'content.html');
    $dom = new \DOMDocument();
    $dom->loadHTML($html);
    var_dump($dom->getElementById('panel_header'));
```

I can target the element by its **ID**, and read the contents of an element and more.

But i can't find its style properties.

Because i need to clone it or change with new parameters.

How to read its style properties and change ?

Is it possible ?

Any other solutions ?

Comment: You can read the style attribute of an element if it is set, sure. But style sheet rules are separate from that, they are not part of the DOM.

Comment: try $node->getAttribute('style'), it will give value of style property

Comment: OK, but how could i update that property, I filter the string to fetch the data as "color: rgb(255, 0, 0)". I need this to "color: rgb(155,10,0)". How could i replace to the same dom.

Comment: @Naisa purushotham , Thanks for your support.

Comment: for setting attributes $node->setAttribute('style','your style property values')

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can try this:If CSS is on the same page you can try this:

```
    $html = file_get_contents('testing.html');
    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    $dom->loadHTML($html);
    $div = $dom->getElementById('test');
    if ($div->hasAttributes()) {
        foreach ($div->attributes as $attr) {
            $name = $attr->nodeName;
            $value = $attr->nodeValue;
            if( strcmp($name,"class") == 0){
                $x=getStyle($dom->textContent,".$value{","}");
                echo "<pre>";
                print_r($x);
             }
             if( strcmp($name,"id") == 0){
                $idCss=getStyle($dom->textContent,"#$value{","}");
                echo "<pre>";
                print_r($idCss);
             }
         }
    }


     function getStyle($string, $start, $end){
        $string = ' ' . $string;
        $ini = strpos($string, $start);
        if ($ini == 0) return '';
        $len = strpos($string, $end, $ini);
        return substr($string, $ini, $len);
    }
```

**to update the style you can use.**

```
$div->setAttribute('style', 'background-color:blue;'); 
     echo $dom->saveHTML(); exit;.
```

**testing.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="test" class="stl" style="width:100px;">

</div>
</body>
</html>

<style>
.stl{
background-color:green;
}

</style>
```

**output:**

```
.stl{
background-color:green;
}
```

if you are looking for only style you can do this:

```
$html = file_get_contents('testing.html');
        $dom = new DOMDocument();
        $dom->loadHTML($html);
    $div = $dom->getElementById('test');
    if ($div->hasAttributes()) {
        echo $div->getAttribute('style');//width:100px;
    }
```

Comment: nice, but its only returning inline css.

Comment: i think you can get the class name but not the defined `css` inside.

Comment: OK, but how could i update that property, I filter the string to fetch the data as "color: rgb(255, 0, 0)". I need this to "color: rgb(155,10,0)". How could i replace to the same dom.

Comment: @ShankarThiyagaraajan  I think you can't you can only set the attribute value to do so it should be inline css.

Comment: @Suchit, Yah, i understand. I make it as inline. So now what are the feasible ways to replace the elements and save it back to the same file.

Comment: you can try  **$div->setAttribute('style', 'background-color:blue;'); echo $dom->saveHTML();
   exit;.**

Comment: Update your last comment to your answer. I will accept it.

Comment: @ShankarThiyagaraajan i have added it in seperate part as guide.Id this helped you the you can upvote and accept it.Thanks.

Comment: @Suchit, Thanks for your support.

Answer (score 2):

A DOM parser will only let you read data that is in the DOM.

It won't load CSS, apply it to the DOM, and then provide you access to the computed properties of the element.

To achieve that you need to take a different approach and use a tool which does apply CSS to the DOM. The most common ones are [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/) and [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) ([PHP bindings](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=phantomJS%20php%20bindings) are available) (they also execute JavaScript).

Comment: Thanks for your support.